# click button on popover view in applescript

Tags: automation, applescript, popover

I am working on an applescript automation project. I can't find a way to click on the button on a popover window. (My system is MacOS Sierra 10.12.6)
Please see the picture:

[accessibility inspector screenshot of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0oc3.png)

The button's parent is

```
<empty desctiption> (popover) [_NSPopoverWindow]
```

Now I didn't find a way to reference this button. Here is what I tried:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NordVPN"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2  --open the popover window to access the button on the window

        delay 0.5

        --get the entire contents of menu bar 2
        --click (button whose title is "Preferences")
        --click button 1 of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        --click button 1 of NSPopover of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        --click button 1 of NSPopover of menu bar 2
        --click button 1 of popover of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click button 1 of _NSPopoverWindow of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        --click button 1 of window 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        --click button 1
    end tell
end tell
```

They all failed. And cannot find useful info on Google and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with GUI scripting, always, is determine the hierarchy of GUI elements so that you can properly reference the one you want. From the screenshot you gave, I'd try the following as a first effort:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NordVPN"
        tell second menu bar
            tell first button
                click --open the popover window to access the button on the window

                delay 0.5
                tell first pop over
                    tell button "Preferences"
                        click
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to work your way up the hierarchy using the `UI Elements` reference or the `entire contents` property of each given element. For instance, you can could say:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NordVPN"
        tell second menu bar
            tell first button
                click --open the popover window to access the button on the window

                delay 0.5
                tell first pop over
                    -- to get a list of all the contents of the the popover 
                    entire contents

                    -- to get the immediate (first level) contents of the popover
                    UI elements
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

either of which will give a list in the Script Editor log of the elements of the popover. You can then experiment with the elements to find a path down to the element you want.

GUI scripting is always a trial-and-error process; this will just help you focus in on what to try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ted Wrigley. It still doesn't work. I go to another way. Since I can click first button correctly, I use applescript to get the position of the first button, then use MouseTools to move the cursor to the second button, the Button "Preference" on the pop over, then use Keyboard Maestro to click at this position. It works for now, I ll keep testing.